# How to determine which site uses a file in Chrome Cache?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

I have a file that my malware detector has flagged.

C:\Users\example\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache\f_0348d3\Gzip

How do I find out which site gave me that file so I can avoid that site in the future?  The Google Chrome answer is key, but I hope to find the answer for other browsers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the tool in the link : [chrome_cache_view](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html).

In the URL field of the cache file , you can find the site information.

Hope this helps.